# How to pass std::cin to a class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, cin, istream

I am trying to create a class which can read input from either a file stream or `std::cin`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

class A
{
public:
  explicit A(std::istream& input)
    : input_(input)
  {
    ;
  }

public:
  void doSomething()
  {
    std::string word;
    while (input_ >> word) {
      std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }
  }

private:
  std::istream& input_;

  std::mutex mutex_;
};

int main()
{
  auto a = A(std::cin);
  a.doSomething();
  return 0;
}
```

But the compiler gives the following output:

```sh
~/test/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
~/test/main.cpp:31:22: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
   auto a = A(std::cin);
                      ^
~/test/main.cpp:5:7: note: ‘A::A(A&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class A
       ^
~/test/main.cpp:5:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/mutex:43:0,
                 from ~/test/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_mutex.h:97:5: note: declared here
     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
     ^~~~~
```

How should I fix the error? Or generally, how do we create a class that can read input either from a file stream or `std::cin`?

---

**Edit**

- Initially I tried to reduce the amount of code as much as possible, and in that process, I removed `std::mutex` part, which gave a very different compiler output. Plus, there was a typo where `input_` was `std::stream` and @JerryJeremiah was correct in the first comment that it should be `std::istream &`.
- Now, I think the question doesn't quite match the problem, as @acraig5075 also pointed out in the comment. And there are similar questions on Stack Overflow already, so I'm going to delete my question.

Comment: You can't copy a stream.  Store a reference to it instead.  Change you member from `std::istream input_;` to `std::istream & input_;`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Ah, sorry my bad; you are correct. I tried to minimize the code and posted it here, and I missed to make `input_` a reference to `std::istream`, which makes the compilation output very different.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I fixed the code in the question to include the part that initially caused the compilation error that was confusing to me.

Comment: The question title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

`std::mutex` is not copyable, and the class containing it becomes not-copyable as well.

The code should be:

```cpp
int main()
{
  A a(std::cin);
  a.doSomething();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good job pushing though and finding the answer.